# Get html and text content from XML between two elements

Tags: javascript

I have read all of the previous entries for getting html/text node content between two elements but it is not working for me.

I have tried a mix of jQuery and pure javascript, but again nothing.

I am trying to work from xml code. I have no control over the xml - it is straight from the World English Bible XML.

```
var xml='<p><v id="1" />In the beginning, God<f caller="+">The Hebrew word rendered “God” is “אֱלֹהִ֑ים” (Elohim).</f> created the heavens and the earth. <ve />'
+'<v id="2" />The earth was formless and empty. Darkness was on the surface of the deep and God’s Spirit was hovering over the surface of the waters. <ve /></p>'
+'<p><v id="3" />God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light. <ve />'
+'<v id="4" />God saw the light, and saw that it was good. God divided the light from the darkness. <ve />'
+'<v id="5" />God called the light “day”, and the darkness he called “night”. There was evening and there was morning, the first day. <ve /></p>';
```

What i need to do is get all the html (text and html) between the `<v>` element and the `<ve>` element and wrap it in a `<span>` so that I can use css on individual verses.

```
//original
<v id="1" />In the beginning, God<f caller="+">The Hebrew word rendered “God” is “אֱלֹהִ֑ים” (Elohim).</f> created the heavens and the earth. <ve />
//becomes
<span class=v id=GEN0101>In the beginning, God<f caller="+">The Hebrew word rendered “God” is “אֱלֹהִ֑ים” (Elohim).</f> created the heavens and the earth. </span>
```

I have tried jQuery using `nextUntil()`, but it only modifies the `<f>` element.

```
var $x=$(xml);
$x.find("v").nextUntil("ve").css('background','red');
$("#content").append($x);
```

Here is my fiddle: [JSFiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/EDLgz/7/)

I've tried pure javascript, and I cannot get that to work either.

```
var v = xml.getElementsByTagName("ve")[0].previousSibling.textContent;
$("#content").append('<div>'+v+'</div>');
```

Thank you

Comment: Why not, instead of having one tag before the text and a completely different tag after the text, you just put the opening tag before and the closing tag after for the v element?

e.g.: `<v id="1">Some Text</v>`

Comment: @SamuelReid - read the question: "I have no control over the xml - it is straight from the World English Bible XML"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could come up with was using jQuery's `contents()` function.  Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DKXMx/

Comment: Your fiddle gave me the basis. However, when I try to use it on a whole book - say the gospel of Matthew it crashes. It takes up too much memory and throws an error. I had to go back to using pure javascript for the iteration and not using jquery.

Comment: If you're using pure javascript sucessfully, then great.  If not, then I'm not sure using pure javascript will get you any better results.